# Facebook .SDK for .NET error in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting a strange error while using a Facebook .SDK for .NET. I'm writing my first application that will use this wrapper and I don't know how can I fix this error:

> An exception of type 'Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send.

In following code:

```
var accessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
client.AppId = _facebookAppId;
dynamic aboutMeResult = await client.GetTaskAsync("/me"); // here an error occurs
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)aboutMeResult;
var data = ((IEnumerable<object>)result["data"]).ToList();
var aboutMe = (IDictionary<string, object>)data[0];
Profile.CreateProfile((string)aboutMe["first_name"] + " " + (string)aboutMe["last_name"], true);
```

I'm using windows 8.1 and visual studio 2013 and I'm creating a store app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.GetCompleted += async(o1, e1) =>
{
    if (e1.Error != null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var result1 = (IDictionary<string, object>)e1.GetResultData();


    JObject jobj1 = JObject.Parse(e1.GetResultData().ToString());
    JArray x1 = (JArray)jobj1["data"];   

};
await client.GetTaskAsync("me/permissions?");
```

Cheers!